# using group() breaks getSelectCountSql in magento

Tags: magento

When I'm using

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id')
```

or

```
$collection->groupByAttribute('entity_id')
```

It breaks getSelectCountSql and I'm getting 1 record and 1 page.
Magento does

```
$countSelect->columns('COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id)');
```

Is there a way to fix it?

I run into it,While overriding _prepareCollection of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use a normal php count() on the returned collection?

Comment: Because it's a mysql thing not a php thing.
When you call count on a collection, php calls the function that execute a mysql query.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I updated the **lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php** file to allow this as I had to have it work. You'll have to keep track of this for upgrades but it works.

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{   
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);

    // Count doesn't work with group by columns keep the group by 
    if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {
        $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->distinct(true);
        $group = $this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);
        $countSelect->columns("COUNT(DISTINCT ".implode(", ", $group).")");
    } else {
        $countSelect->columns('COUNT(*)');
    }
    return $countSelect;
}
```

Comment: Varien classes can be overridden in the `app/code/local` directory the same way as Mage classes are. Use that instead of 'keeping track for upgrades'.

Comment: +1 to @clockworkgeek - 4 years of solid Magento work and I never knew you could override lib/Varien from app/code/local. Cheers.

Comment: To clarify: copy lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php to app/code/local/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php and edit it there.

Comment: This did not work for me in Magento 1.5 for product collections because the method is overridden in a child class: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection` I made the change there. But I also had to make other changes in order for layered navigation to take into account my reduced product count.

Comment: It's better to rewrite the collection class that is using the group by.

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day!  But as Steve Robbins said, it's way better to just put this method in your own model collection-class, since it extends all the way down to Db.php

Comment: Does anyone know what the equivalent of this is in Magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

in some cases, the method from Eric doesn't work.

It's better to rewrite the `getSize()` method to

```
    public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();

        $result = $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql, $this->_bindParams);;

        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $this->_totalRecords += reset($row);
        }

    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this using the function below:

```
public function getSize()
{
    return sizeof( $this->getAllIds());
}
```

This helped me in issue of `getSize()` returning 1 count of product collection in Magento CE 1.5.

I have overwritten the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection` file and place above function.

Answer (score 0):

Very nice article
Here are few changes I made in order to make it work for me

Changes suggested in Db.php are not required for resolving group by in catalog collection. 
I made the similar change in 
    Catalog->model->Ressource->EAV->Mysql4->product->collection.php 
Here is the code I added to getSelectCountSql()

```
if(count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) { $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP); }
```

After this things get resolved but a new issue comes in .. In Layered navigation quantities for all the filters is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I made it without touching Core files by overriding the getSize() method of my collection.

```
public function getSize()
{
    if (count($this->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP)) > 0) {

        // Create a new collection from ids because we need a fresh select
        $ids = $this->getAllIds();
        $new_coll = Mage::getModel('module_key/model')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $ids));

        // return the collection size
        return $new_coll->getSize();
    }

    return parent::getSize();
}
```

Tell me if that works for you..

Bouni