# getSelectCountSql() does not reset Group part

Tags: mysql, magento

In *lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php* there's a method **getSelectCountSql()** that is inherited by all Magento Collections. In this method the Select object is cloned, and prepared to be used specifically to get COUNT value for collection items not loading the collection, but quering the DB with light-weighted Select instead.

The preparation is done by resetting the unnecessary parts of the Select and parts that could affect the COUNT results. Here's the code:

```
public function getSelectCountSql()
{   
    $this->_renderFilters();
    $countSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
    ...
```

I want to know, is there a real reason why Magento engineers didn't include `$countSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::GROUP);` along with other parts.

Magento seems to not addressing this issue from revision to revision, and I was dead sure this is a bug, so maybe I'm wrong? I would appreciate, if someone can explain the reasoning behind **NOT INCLUDING** the GROUP part into reset parts list.

PS this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485455/using-group-breaks-getselectcountsql-in-magento), I know how to add the fix, I just want to get an explanation (if it exists) why Magento engineers haven't done it from the start, and continue ignoring the issue.

Comment: Interesting question. I personally don't consider this to be buggy, I guess it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If I were to create a collection of items that have style and colour attributes, and I wanted the unique colours (therefore grouping by colour), I would expect the count of the collection to be the number of unique colours, not the total number of items in my table.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Cags - it totally makes sense, but this seems to be more like unique scenario. More often grouping is used on the entity_id field (or whatever the increment is called) to prevent duplicate entries when joining multiple tables. So it would make more sense to me to reset `group` for this more often scenario to work correctly. But anyway, your point is pretty convincing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a bug, I was wrong in my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in my Magento CE 1.9.2.2 (although I'm not sure which version first included it).