# Massaction broken in Orders grid after group() query (Magento 1.7)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

This is a follow-up from the following question, partially answered now: [Adding custom columns in order grid (Magento 1.7.0.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515338/adding-custom-columns-in-order-grid-magento-1-7-0-0/14536886#14536886), this is the problem:

When I use the query:

```
$collection->getSelect()->join('magento_sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = magento_sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',array('telephone', 'email'));
```

Along with `$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id')` (which points to the right id to use in the group) in the `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`, the id used by the `_prepareMassAction()` function is the entity_id from the joined table (in my case, magento_sales_flat_order_address as order_address), and not the entity_id from the main_table as it should be.

I've tried changing this value `$this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');` in the `_prepareMassAction()` function to point to the right id to use, but it's as if nothing I put in the parenthesis works. When I change it to ANY value (aside from null or empty), it keeps pointing to the 'entity_id' from the order_address table, I even checked to see if it was being set properly like this:

```
echo getMassactionIdField();
```

And the output was the ID I was inputting in the `setMassactionIdField()` (for example, parent_id), so it was being set properly, and YET the result was clearly using the entity_id. So either this is a bug or there's something I'm not doing properly here.

Comment: You don't want to work in the Zend_Db_Select. If you use the magento functions, for example `joinTable()`, magento does everything for you. Have a look here: http://blog.fabian-blechschmidt.de/articles/Joining-a-flat-table-on-EAV.html an on `joinAttribute()`, `joinField()`

Comment: I'll try what you're suggesting and see if that solves the problems I'm having. Previously I was using joins and groups directly on the query object, and I was having problems as well so I had to make a few modifications in the `lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php` (copied to /local/, of course).

Comment: Hi again. I checked your article and tried to use the function, but turns out it throws the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection::joinTable()`. For some reason I can't use joinTable for collections now, and it's not listed in the available methods (`print_r(get_class_methods(get_class($collection)));`).