# use multiple _prepareCollection()'s

Tags: magento, collections

Got this code (in: app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php):

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR "<br>")')))->group('sales_flat_order_item.entity_id');
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_payment', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',array('method'))->group('sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

When I comment the line below COL 1 or COL 2 this works fine, but I want them to work *both*, how is this done? (if I use them at the same time I get an error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'entity_id' in group statement is ambiguous`)

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:**

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR "<br>")')));
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_payment', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.parent_id',array('method'))->group('main_table.entity_id');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the error, the table to apply the group to cannot be determined.  You need to explicitly define the table:

```
...->group('sales_flat_order_item.entity_id');
```

Comment: Ow jeah, indeed the grouping was wrong! Thanks! (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

echo your query by using echo (string) $collection->getSelect(); You will get a plain sql query here. 
Fire that query in database and check, are you getting results the way you want.
Also last but not the least Group also create problem. 
Have a look at below link
[using group() breaks getSelectCountSql in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485455/using-group-breaks-getselectcountsql-in-magento)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did that already and the single SQL queries are working fine, but when I use them together is this situation it creates the mentioned error.

Comment: Hey use tablename.entity_id there